# Only a specific account is blocked for sign in with Google OAuth API

Tags: google-oauth, oauth2-playground

I've set a OAuth consent screen without adding any user into test users for a testing applicaiotn. It turns out that I can login with all the Google accounts except specific one. The questions are

1. Why can I login with those Google accounts without adding them to test users?
2. Why is the specific Google account blocked by the system?

Thanks.